# In python, frozenset's subclass's __init__ method throw TypeError of arguments number

Tags: python, python-2.7, frozenset

The class's `__init__` method has 3 arguments, but when I instantiate it with 3 arguments, it throw an error that it expected 1 arguments. I cannot undrestand.

```
class ArrObj(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, elem_list, elem_count, self_count):
        super(ArrObj, self).__init__(elem_list)  # Enums, ArrObj, race_id
        self.elem_count = elem_count
        self.self_count = self_count
        assert self_count > 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ArrObj(['a', 'b', 'c'], {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, 8)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pycharm-projects/new_keyinfo/verify_treekeys.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = ArrObj(['a', 'b', 'c'], {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, 8)
TypeError: ArrObj expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: You probably need to implement `__new__`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you tell me why need I implement `__new__` method?  normaly, I just need implement the `__init__` method.

Comment: `__new__` exists, in part, because you can't initialize an immutable object after it has been created. `__new__` creates, `__init__` initializes after creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frozenset.__init__` doesn't take additional arguments, because you can't modify a `frozenset` after it has been created. (In fact, `frozenset` doesn't define `__init__` at all; it just uses the `__init__` it inherits from `object`.) The iterable you pass to `frozenset` is consumed by `frozenset.__new__` instead.

```
class ArrObj(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, elem_list, elem_count, self_count):
        # May as well assert this before you do any more work
        assert self_count > 0

        obj = super().__new__(cls, elem_list)
        obj.elem_count = elem_count
        obj.self_count = self_count
        return obj
```

Comment: ... Why is it like this?